# Add custom sheet on button on the bottom

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if you can assign the button on the attached screenshot a new function. It's the one at the bottom of a Excel file; one where you generate a custom sheet (e.g. automatically a specific title, add content etc.)

[image: Image with button next to Sheet1 on a Excel workbook]

Comment: No - you can't customize the button.  There is a `Workbook_NewSheet` event which you might be able to use to perform the auto-rename part.  Or create a button to add a new sheet and name it.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like this vba code to create a new tab and edit the contents of the sheet.

```
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
   Dim wsName As String
   'Name the new sheet
   wsName = "New Sheet"
    
   wb.Sheets.Add.Name = wsName
    
   Set ws = Sheets(wsName)
   'Edit content of sheet, example cell A1
   ws.Range("A1").Value = "Cool!"
```